# Is there any way having restrictions on dags by their owners upon roles

Tags: linux, docker-compose, airflow, airflow-2.x

*I have some dags owner by user 'abc' and I want to this user a role with permissions to show just  those dags on airflow GUI which are owned by user 'abc' and this user can pause or unpause or run its own owned dag. Just to clear here that I cannot use RBAC as RBAC is cloud based authentication , I am having Airflow 2.5.2 installed over docker-compose.*

````
   ```airflow roles del-perms [-h] [-a [ACTION [ACTION ...]]] -r
                    [RESOURCE [RESOURCE ...]] [-v]
                    [role [role ...]]```
````

Answer (score 1):

From airflow docs, [dag-level permission](https://For%20example,%20if%20a%20user%20is%20trying%20to%20view%20DAG%20information%20for%20the%20example_dag_id,%20and%20the%20endpoint%20requires%20DAGs.can_read%20access,%20access%20will%20be%20granted%20if%20the%20user%20has%20either%20DAGs.can_read%20or%20DAG:example_dag_id.can_read%20access)

For example, if a user is trying to view DAG information for the example_dag_id, and the endpoint requires DAGs.can_read access, access will be granted if the user has either DAGs.can_read or DAG:example_dag_id.can_read access

You need to set to user permissions per dag and remove the Dags global permission.

Comment: I used control_access () inside dag .py file to have control for users